# Hide and Re-order columns inside a new Content type will not have any effect on the Create & Edit forms for the List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, content-type, site-column

I did the follow:-

1. I added a new Content type, and I specify to have “Issue” content type as its parent.
2. Then I added 5 site columns, and I added them to the new Content Type.so the new content type will have the fields from the parent Issue and the five custom columns
3. Now I create a new Issue Tracking App inside my team site.
4. And I change the default content type for the list to use my custom content type instead of the default Issue content type as follow:-

[image]

5. i specify the following order columns and i specify to hide these columns:-
   [image]

but now if I hide or re-order the columns inside my custom content type it will not have any effect on the create form which looks as follow:-

[image]

For example I have specified that the AssinedTo should be hidden , and I specify different order, can anyone advice on this please?
Can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Click on "Assigned To" column from content type settings page.

Make the change.

Then select "Update all content types inheriting from this type"

Click Ok.

Comment: i already did this ,, mainly i modify the columns (hide & re-order) from the content type settings and i had this reflected inside the List's content type... can you advice more on this please? so manily if you go to site Gallary at the site level or from the content type inside the list you will see the same settings ..

Comment: If you are making any changes to the parent content type then you should propagate those changes. To do that while making the changes you should select "Update all content types inheriting from this type" radio button to "Yes"

Comment: but i did not modify the parent Issue content type, i just inherite from it to get the defualt columns, then inside my new content type i chose to hide and re-order the columns ..

Comment: so for example inside the Issue content type i have the Assingedto column set as required, while insdie the new content type i chose to hide it .. but when creating a new item from my list which is based on the new content type the Assinged To column will still be shown ...

Comment: By parent I meant the new content type you created. When you set the new content type to a list (that list will localize a copy of the assigned content type)

Comment: yes i already modify the new custom content type from the site collection level (not from the list level), and i got the changies applied to the content type inside my list, but this will have not effect on the Create & Edit forms...

Comment: ,, could the problem be that i can not  re-order column for any custom content type using the list setting UI ???

Comment: also i have created a new Create form based on the new content type ,, so could the problem is that if i define a new Create form based on a new content type,, then i will not be able to modify the Create form column from the list settings UI ?